# How to instantiate custom class UICollectionViewCell outside CollectionView delegate methods?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have trouble instantiating custom class UICollectionViewCell in my custom method. I already have desired NSIndexPath that i need, i only need to instantiate that one cell so i can put some progress view in it...

Here is my example code:

```
-(void)setupProgressAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    StoreViewCell *cell = [self.collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    _progressBackground = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cell.frame.size.width/6,cell.frame.size.height/6,80,80)];
    else if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
        _progressBackground = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cell.frame.size.width/4,cell.frame.size.height/4,80,80)];

    _progressBackground.alpha = 0.95;
    _progressBackground.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    _progressBackground.layer.cornerRadius = 20.0f;
    _progressBackground.hidden=NO;

    _progressView = [[M13ProgressViewPie alloc] init];
    _progressView.backgroundRingWidth=2.0;
    _progressView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,64,64);
    _progressView.clipsToBounds=YES;
    _progressView.center = CGPointMake(40,40);
    _progressView.primaryColor=[UIColor orangeColor];
    _progressView.secondaryColor=[UIColor orangeColor];

    [_progressBackground setHidden:YES];

    [_progressBackground addSubview:_progressView];
    [cell.magazineImage addSubview:_progressBackground];

}
```

Ok i call this in delegate method -collectionView: didSelectItemAtIndexPath:

There is only one problem, when i tap on some cell, it puts progress view there but cell loses it's data and becomes nil. Other that that all works fine. I think the only problem is this line of code:

```
StoreViewCell *cell = [self.collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Is there any other resolution to my problem, is there any other way to instantiate cell without losing data, i need some answers! :)

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/34242936/656600, it have a demo project attached collectionView.

Comment: where you using -(void)setupProgressAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath ? have you use that instantiated cell in collection view?

Comment: i call [self setupProgressAtIndexPath:indexPath] in didSelectItemAtIndexPath: i mentioned that before...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
StoreViewCell *cell = [self.collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

extract the existing cell at that index:

```
StoreViewCell * cell = [self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Even if it might work I suggest you to put _progressBackground and _progressView related stuff inside the StoreViewCell class as hidden and then unhide them only when you need to

Comment: Ok this kinda works, but now it misses the correct indexPath, i have no idea why... For example: when i tap on 3rd cell in first row, it places ProgressView in 1st cell in first row... And so on... Only when i tap on 1st cell in first row it places correctly >.<

Answer (score 2):

```
StoreViewCell *cell = [self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

#### Explanation:

`- cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath`  returns nil
 if cell is not visible or index path is out of range. This doesn't create cells, only gives you access to them. I think it should be avoided as much as possible to prevent accidental leaks and other interference with the tableView.

Comment: Ok but what do you suggest I should do :(

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
StoreViewCell *cell = [self.collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

with

```
 StoreViewCell *cell = [self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

to get the existing cell to update - you shouldn't be creating a new cell.

Comment: Thank you for answer :) Rate up! It kinda works now, but it misses the correct indexPath i have no idea why :(

Comment: that must be in how you get the index path to pass to this method

Comment: Well i get indexPath from delegate method didSelectItemAtIndexPath: i don't know why it misses, i will try something thx anyway for the support man! :)